# datepicker date space issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have used java script date picker in my form. This is my html

```
<form name="adduser" id="adduser" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return form_val();">
<div class="form">
<div class="fields">
<div class="field">
<div class="label">
<label for="input-error">Date of Birth:</label>
</div>
<div class="input">
<input name="dob" type="text" class="date_small" onClick="cal_value();" id="calendar1" value="" />  
</div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

This my php code.

```
<?php
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$dobseparate=explode('/',$dob);
$date = $dobseparate[0];
$month = $dobseparate[1];
$year = $dobseparate[2];
echo $dbdob=$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date;

?>
```

If i select a date and submit the form the value displayed at the top of the form. My problem is the year is displayed with a space after it. I don't know why this space appears.

This is the internal script that i have used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        //<![CDATA[

            $(document).ready(function (){ 

                $("#calendar1, #calendar2, #calendar3, #calendar4, #calendar5, #calendar6, #calendar7,#calendar8,#calendar9, #calendar10,#calendar11, #calendar12, #calendar13,#calendar14, #calendar15,#calendar16, #calendar17 , #calendar18").calendar();

                $("#calendar1_alert").click(function(){alert(popUpCal.parseDate($('#calendar1').val()))});

            });

        //]]>

        </script>
```

Please see this location for my date picker script only `http://jsfiddle.net/e9Jbv/`

I have to remove that space. How can i do that?

Comment: Instead of giving all elements unique IDs, you could just assign them to a class, using, for example, `$(".calendarElement").calendar();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function TRIM to remove the space.  It might be quicker than searching all the javascript to find where/why it's being added.

```
$date = $dobseparate[0];
$month = $dobseparate[1];
$year = trim($dobseparate[2]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php